# Getting strange characters when trying to read UTF-8 document from URL

Tags: java, file-io

When I am trying to read the following URL and store it to a local file

```
private void testStoreFeedToLocalFile() throws IOException{
SyndFeed feed = null;
InputStream is = null;      
try {        
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy_url", proxy_port_number));
    URLConnection openConnection = new URL("http://www.deutschlandradio.de/podcast-bildung-und-wissenschaft.419.de.podcast").openConnection(proxy);
    HttpURLConnection httpOpenConnection = (HttpURLConnection)openConnection;
    if(httpOpenConnection.getResponseCode() >= 400){
        is = httpOpenConnection.getErrorStream();
    } else {
        is = httpOpenConnection.getInputStream();
    }

    Reader inReader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inReader);

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter
            (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/feed.xml"), "UTF-8"));  

    String feedText = null;
    while ((feedText = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // Keep in mind that readLine() strips the newline characters
        writer.write(feedText + "\n");
        System.out.println(feedText);
    }
    writer.close();

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\n ++++++++++++++ ERROR testStoreFeedToLocalFile ++++++++++++++ \n");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("\n \n");    
} finally {
    if(is!=null){
        is.close();
    }
}
```

}

I get a bunch of strange characters (??9j?n^????P?? etc), both on the console and in the feed.xml created file. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the source is UTF8?

Comment: As per @CodeChimp - the input file is not a UTF-8 file anyway, it's a compressed (GZip) file, and it's contents are XML.

Comment: Yes thank you guys you were Eyes openers. I just looked at the URL through the browser and it takes care of the decompressing automatically. It works after adding one line of code :      GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(is);
      Reader inReader = new InputStreamReader(gzis, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you feel the need to translate the stream in to characters at all. Why don't you just pass the bytes through using Streams instead of Reader/Writer?

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/feed.xml"), "UTF-8")
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int len = 0;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
os.flush();
os.close();
```

---

## EDIT:

The inut stream is compressed:

```
~/junk $ curl -v -O http://www.deutschlandradio.de/podcast-bildung-und-wissenschaft.419.de.podcast
* About to connect() to www.deutschlandradio.de port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 217.69.91.96... connected
* Connected to www.deutschlandradio.de (217.69.91.96) port 80 (#0)
> GET /podcast-bildung-und-wissenschaft.419.de.podcast HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.12.9.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
> Host: www.deutschlandradio.de
> Accept: */*
> 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache
< P3P: CP="NOI NID ADMa OUR IND UNI COM NAV"
< Expires: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 15:48:50 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, pre-check=60, no-transform
< Pragma:
< Last-modified: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 15:47:51 GMT
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< X-DW-Server: www05
< Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 5111
< Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 15:53:18 GMT
< X-Varnish: 1993556337 1993540162
< Age: 327
< Via: 1.1 varnish
< Connection: keep-alive
```

You need to identify this, and handle it appropriately:

```
if ("gzip".equals(httpOpenConnection.getContentEncoding()) {
    is = new GZipInputStream(is);
}
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/feed.xml"), "UTF-8")
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int len = 0;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Comment: 10x rolfl. Now I also know how I can identify this.